# How to pass interface instance in class constructor in php

Tags: php, oop, constructor, interface, instance

I have the following class

```
class InterfaceImplementation{
    public function __construct(ServiceInterface $oService){
        $this->oService = $oService;
    }
}
```

When I create the class object

```
$obj = new InterfaceImplementation();
```

How to pass the interface instance?And is this the correct way to code?

Comment: I was stumbled upon this question ytd too, I think it means to pass an object that implement that specific interface instead of passing the literal interface itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object that will implement `ServiceInterface` can be used and pass to the constructor. 
You have to create an instance of the class, but in `InterfaceImplementation` you will use the interface API (methods declarated in the interface), not the methods from the particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can create a new `InterfaceImplementation`, you need to have a valid `ServiceInterface` object. Once you have the service object you can pass it while creating `InterfaceImplementation`

```
$service = new ServiceInterface(); // make sure its a valid object
$implementation = new InterfaceImplementation($service);
```

Pro tip: Look up a dependency injection container. It will make your life so much easier.